# CosmosDB Linq query with contains is not of type IDocumentQuery

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a project working woth CosmosDB. At first I used the preview for EFCore, but it really isn't mature enough so I decided to opt with [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) instead. I have a linq statement which basically looks if two properties contains a list of substrings - basically I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.Name, ListOfNames) AND CONTAINS(c.Producer, ListOfProducers);
```

Or a huge ass bunch of:

```
foreach(var name in nameList) {
    foreach(var producer in producerList){

        SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Name == searchedName AND c.Producer == searchedProducer;
    }
}
```

This worked with the EFCore SQL adapter with the following Linq Query:

```
public async void Search(List<string> producers, List<string> names){

 await _store.Entity.Where(x => producers.Any(p => x.Producer.Contains(p)) && names.Any(w => x.Name.Contains(w))).ToListAsync()
}
```

However, this with the cosmonaut library (which wraps the DocumentDB client from cosmos) gives the following exception:

`Input is not of type IDocumentQuery`

Looking at the [specs for Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) I can do this:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT Name  
FROM Production.Product  
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, '"chain*" OR "full*"');  
GO
```

But doing the following in the CosmosDB data explorer yields 0 results:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.Name, '"Test" OR "Test2"')
```

Whereas a regular contains does:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE CONTAINS(c.Name, "Test")
```

Maybe my strategy is just wrong. The main reason I want to combine it is to have better performance. My search domain is around 100.000 documents where I have a list of up to a 1000 of producer + names. So basically I want to see if I can find the given producer + name combination in my document list.

Best Regards

Comment: Hello, I'm the Cosmonaut developer. Can you paste the full Cosmonaut query snippet so I can help you? This error is thrown when you are building an IQueryable which is not coming from the Query() method of the `CosmosStore`.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the reply. It's literally just injected as per usual as an ICosmosStore<Entity> and then thrown in _store from the constructor. so the .Query() function is on that and of the type IQueryable<entity>.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should not mix T-SQL and Cosmos SQL API. Cosmos db has sql-like query syntax but it doesn't support T-SQL(it's for MS SQL).

Secondly, `CONTAINS` in [Cosmos SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-reference#bk_contains) is a string operator so you cannot use it for arrays.

I think you're looking for `IN` [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#in-keyword).

So actually you need next query:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE (c.Name IN("Test", "Test2")) AND (c.Producer IN("Producer1", "Producer2"))
```

I have not used cosmonaut library but in Microsoft LINQ provider for Document DB your query should look like this:

```
var data = yourQueryable.Where(x => producers.Contains(x.Producer) && names.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
```

Comment: That works like a charm - I swear I have tried that but I guess the journey has been long and my eyes have been deceiving. Thanks!