# Linq query Cosmos db with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to query cosmos db with Linq, but with a list of objects, return all the items in cosmos that's equal to these objects.

I want to Achieve this behavior, but with List each object contain multiple properties, not List:

[CosmosDB Linq query with contains is not of type IDocumentQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56427610/cosmosdb-linq-query-with-contains-is-not-of-type-idocumentquery)

is't possible?

my workaround so far was to save lists of each property I needed and it worked, but it's not the best solution.

```
subs.Contains(item.Properties.sub) &&
 names.Contains(item.Properties.name) &&
 ids.Contains(item.Properties.id)`
```

the query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT VALUE root
FROM root
WHERE (root["properties"]["sub"] IN ("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", "11111111-1111-1111-1111-1111111111"))
AND (root["properties"]["Name"] IN ("Test1", "Test2"))
AND (root["properties"]["Id"] IN ("id1", "id2")))
```

Comment: You can append `.Where()` calls to effectively compose an `AND` condition, eg `if(someFlag) { query=query.Where(...);}`. LINQ operators return a new query, they don't modify an existing one. You can compose a query call-by-call

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data, as well as your attempt (and specific issue) in C#/Linq, plus expected vs actual output, errors, etc. Right now, you haven't shown anything specific, other than a general requirement.